# Threading on File Import (Python)

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7

I am trying to create a simple simulation that does file import and export.

But the problem I am facing is, I need to allow the simulation to be run in multiple windows

and all of them shares the same `.txt` file for import and export.

So I am trying to integrate Threads in to the problem.

What I think Threads can do for my simulation: (Please correct me if I am wrong)

- Create a loop that will infinitely import the `.txt` file (Like update function?)
- When one of the simulations end, then the `.txt` file import loop in that simulation will end without raising any errors.

If what I think is correct, then can anyone help me how to do this by using Thread?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Please go through [this](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html#module-threading) and [this](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/threading.html#module-threading) link to get more information on threading. You are correct in the sense that threads will help you achieve parallelism in a light-weight mode when compared to multiple processes. And also it will improve efficiency.

HTH!